# isNotNull on a Date column failing 0.82.2

Tags: android, realm

I am reaching out to see if anyone knows if the error is fixed in later versions of Realm since the release notes make mention of changes to Date in 0.83.
Or am I just doing something wrong or out of the ordinary.

Asking because I have a good amount of changes to make to my models to move to 0.83+ before I would be able to find out.

Here is the error.

```
D/REALM: Expected columnType 12 or 13, but got 7
D/REALM: jni: ThrowingException 3, ColumnType invalid: expected type_Link or type_LinkList, .
D/REALM: Exception has been throw: Illegal Argument: ColumnType invalid: expected type_Link or type_LinkList
```

When executing the following.

```
realm.where(Person.class).isNotNull(Person.FIELD_LAST_ACCESS).findAllSorted(Person.FIELD_LAST_ACCESS, false);
```

Snippet from the Person class

```
public class Person extends RealmObject {
    @Ignore
    public static String FIELD_LAST_ACCESS = "lastAccess";
    private Date lastAccess;
    public Date getLastAccess() {
        return lastAccess;
    }

    public void setLastAccess(final Date lastAccess) {
        this.lastAccess = lastAccess;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date` fields can't be null in 0.82.2, so querying with `isNotNull()` on one doesn't make any sense and isn't implemented (it would always match all objects). Support for null dates was added in 0.83.